# DC to DC step-up boost converter compensation pin, what values to use?

Tags: voltage-regulator, boost, buck

Okay, so I decided on a DC to DC boost converter but am having some difficulty figuring out what values to use for the compensation pin capacitors and resistor. The [data-sheet](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/isl9/isl97519a.pdf) really does not go into how to choose these parts other than to provide a range so I am pretty confused on what components to use.

So far, I made my design to have a 9V output and followed the formulas in the datasheet to produce the following schematic:

[image]

How do you go about calculating R3 and C5??

(also, there is an error in the schematic, Fsel should go to ground not Vdd, I am opperating on 620kHz)

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the datasheet. The value of R3 and both of the capacitors don't seem to be very important. At page 2, in a typical application, R3 is 1kOhm and both capacitors ar 4.7nF.
You should go with those values.

Answer (score 2):

On page 7, the data sheet says this: -

> For most applications, the compensation resistor in the range of 0.5k
>   to 7.5k and the compensation capacitor in the range of 3nF to 10nF.

These seem reasonable values if you've had the experience of building a switcher like this from scratch components. The bigger the value of the capacitor the longer it might take the "system" to respond to an output load change BUT the liklihood is that the stability of the output will be better.

Comment: Thanks, so question part 2: Should I be using BOTH capacitors? Why does one say "open"? From other boost circuits I've found they had the series cap and resistor AND the parallel cap, so I assume that means keep it? Should I make it the same value as C5? First time ever building a power supply like this.

Comment: Gut feeling is that the parallel cap would be smaller by a factor of 3 or more. If laying out a PCB track it in but don't fit it is my advice.